# Simple training and testing issue using libsvm C++ in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am trying to execute a simple XOR output prediction using libsvm C++ in Eclipse. This is the code that I have written. The output value should be predicting `a+1` but I always have this error which I cannot solve:

> expected expression before ')' token.

This is the line with the error:

```
#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))"
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "libsvm.h"
#include "main.h"

#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))
// struct svm_node *x = (struct svm_node *) malloc((n+1)*sizeof(struct svm_node));

struct svm_parameter param;     // set by parse_command_line
struct svm_problem prob;        // set by read_problem
struct svm_model *model;
struct svm_node *x_space;
struct svm_node ** x;
struct svm_node *testnode;

void makeModel2(void) // int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //char input_file_name[1024];
    //char model_file_name[1024];
    //const char *error_msg;

    param.svm_type = C_SVC;
    param.kernel_type = RBF;
    param.degree = 3;
    param.gamma = 0.5;
    param.coef0 = 0;
    param.nu = 0.5;
    param.cache_size = 100;
    param.C = 1;
    param.eps = 1e-3;
    param.p = 0.1;
    param.shrinking = 1;
    param.probability = 0;
    param.nr_weight = 0;
    param.weight_label = NULL;
    param.weight = NULL;

    // --- Problem definition ---
    prob.l = 4;

    //x values matrix of xor values
    double matrix[prob.l][2];
    matrix[0][0] = 1;
    matrix[0][1] = 1;

    matrix[1][0] = 1;
    matrix[1][1] = 0;

    matrix[2][0] = 0;
    matrix[2][1] = 1;

    matrix[3][0] = 0;
    matrix[3][1] = 0;

    //This part I have trouble understanding
    struct svm_node** x = (struct svm_node * *)malloc((prob.l)*sizeof(struct svm_node *));
    // svm_node** x = Malloc(svm_node*,prob.l);
    // (x *)malloc((prob.l)*sizeof(prob.l))
    // x = Malloc(x,prob.l);

    //Trying to assign from matrix to svm_node training examples
    for (int row = 0;row <prob.l; row++){
        x_space = Malloc(x_space,3);
        // svm_node* x_space = Malloc(svm_node,3);
        // x_space = Malloc(x_space,3);
        // struct svm_node *x_space = (struct svm_node *) malloc((3)*sizeof(struct svm_node));
        for (int col = 0;col < 2;col++){
            x_space[col].index = col;
            x_space[col].value = matrix[row][col];
        }
        //Each row of properties should be terminated with a -1 according to the readme
        x_space[2].index = -1;      
        x[row] = x_space;
    }

    prob.x = x;

    //yvalues
    prob.y = (double *)malloc((prob.l)*sizeof(double));
    // prob.y = Malloc(double,prob.l); // prob.y = Malloc(prob.y,prob.l);
    prob.y[0] = -1;
    prob.y[1] = 1;
    prob.y[2] = 1;
    prob.y[3] = -1;

    // --- Train model---
    model = svm_train(&prob,&param);
    // svm_model *model = svm_train(&prob,&param);


    // --- Test model ---
    struct svm_node *testnode = (struct svm_node *) malloc((3)*sizeof(struct svm_node));
    // svm_node* testnode = Malloc(svm_node,3);
    // testnode = Malloc(testnode,3);
    // testnode = Malloc(testnode,3);
    testnode[0].index = 0;
    testnode[0].value = 1;
    testnode[1].index = 1;
    testnode[1].value = 0;
    testnode[2].index = -1;

    //This works correctly:
    retval[0] = svm_predict(model,testnode);
    // double retval = svm_predict(model,testnode);
    //printf("retval: %f\n",retval);

    svm_destroy_param(&param);
    free(prob.y);
    free(prob.x);
    free(x_space);

    //return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are two different languages.  The C++ may *mangle* the function names when exporting to a library.  The C++ language has `std::vector` and you can create a Matrix class.  Decide on the single language and remove the other tag.

Comment: In the C++ language, prefer to use `new` and `delete`.  The `new` operator calls the constructor of the object to initialize the members.  The C language only has `malloc`, which doesn't initialize the members.  The `calloc` does not properly initialize the members.

Comment: Prefer not to use macro functions, there is no type checking.  For example, what happens when `Macro("hello", "Frog")` is evaluated?  Replace at the invocations with `new` if you need dynamic memory.

Comment: The statement `double matrix[prob.l][2];` is declaring a *Variable Length Array (VLA)*.  VLAs are not supported by the standard C++ language, but may be provided as an extension by your compiler.  Use `std::vector` instead

Comment: I recommend rewriting to code the remove the pointers.  Search the internet for "C++ FAQ Matrix" to find a matrix class.  Also, read up on `std::list` so you don't need to write your own.

Comment: You use `prob.l` in allocating space, but you have 4 entries hard coded.  What happens when `prob.l` is less than 4 or greater than 4?  The `prob.l` is a *variable* and can change.  You may want to make it a constant instead (e.g. `const unsigned int matrix_rows = 4;`).

Comment: By the way, for some reason you commented out the usage of Malloc that would work, `svm_node* x_space = Malloc(svm_node,3)`. That said,  your usage of free doesn't seem to correspond with your usage of malloc. I'd really echo the comments of other posters about simplifying things by using a container like vector instead of pointers.

Comment: You have an '"' at the end of your macro, is that a copy-paste error?